# Data type and approach for Rails attributes with occasional second value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have a use case where a user clicks on a word and sees information about its base word. Very occasionally there are words with two different but equally accepted spellings with identical meanings, and I'd like to display the alternate spelling when this happens (examples for Spanish: 'video' and 'vídeo', or 'quizá' and 'quizás').

Similarly, there are times where a `base_word` will need two `inflection_forms`.

The `BaseWord` model has attributes for `base_word:string`, `inflection_form:string` (i.e., '`ND3XX`'), and the `language_id`. A `base_word` `has_many :inflections` to handle related words, but it seems silly to create a new inflection for a differently spelled word with an identical grammatical role.

I tried serializing both of the fields into an `Array`, and then later as a `Set`, but in both cases I had trouble querying the database for `base_words` where `base_word` was equal to one of the set/array members.

What is the most logical way to handle this case?

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using Postgres you can use it's built in Array type which can be queried using SQL queries. cf http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_postgresql.html#array

#### Update 1 : Query example

Yes, its not as simple but, assuming you add an `inflections` column of type array to your migration, you should be able to hide the complexity with something like:

```
class BaseWord < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  scope :has_inflection, -> (word) { where('? = ANY(inflections)', word) }
```

And then use it like any other scope. For ex.

```
BaseWord.has_inflection('vídeo').order('base_word').limit(5)
```

Comment: Would this mean that every time I query for a baseword in any situation, that I'd always have to do a direct SQL query? In other words, I would have to go back through and replace my numerous BaseWord.where(base_word: (x)) with a real sql query? (Disclaimer: I've never used SQL directly)

Comment: Good update, thanks - one clarification: are you suggesting that I put the column for inflections on the base word model instead of having a separate model for inflections as is currently the case?

Comment: Based on my limited knowledge of the sittuation, yes, I think it is a good solution for your case, I would certainly consider it better than Rails `serialize`d attributes since you can query the data right on the database. Using a separate table wouldn't necessarily be a bad solution either though, it is certainly more future proof (For example you might need to add meta-data to inflections)

Comment: Ya, so here's the problem: my question refers to querying for different _spellings_ of a given base word, nothing to do with the inflections. The inflections undoubtedly need a separate model, since a base word has many inflections, each of which needs (a) specific POS tag(s) that indicate(s) the specific type of word/conjugation that it is/could be. In other words (no pun intended), I either need the headword of the base word itself to be an array that can store the very rare case in which a base word has multiple spellings, or a separate column on base word that stores alternate spellings.